# How do you style a single TextBox among others?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF textbox among others that I would like to create a style for.

This style should only apply to this type of textbox.

Here is my textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DeviceInformation.SerialNumber, Mode=OneWay}"  BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

My text box basically simulates a label I can copy.

How do I make this into a style and target only this textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `Key` property on your `Style` definition, then it will be applied only on TextBoxes that have set this Style. `Style={StaticResource=ExampleKey}`

Example:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ExampleStyle">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

You can also have application-wide styles defined in App.xaml